# Drupal Registration: Avoiding A Password

Tags: php, security, drupal-6, module

I'm not new to Drupal module development, but am new to the security system. Our users authenticate via a system-wide NetID, so we don't need or want a password. We do, however, still need a local user account so users can post, change their profile, etc.

Because we needed this change fairly quickly, I've modified the `/modules/user/user.module` functions that handle new account creation, so they ignore password information. This isn't ideal. What I'd like to do is leave these changes in our security module and somehow avoid modifying Drupal's core User module.

I have tried using a `hook_user_register` function, but it seemed to be piggy-backing on the existing `user_register` function rather than replacing it.

I'm probably missing something very basic, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This screams "Security alert!" to me. Please be careful with what you're doing here, else you'd open up your system for the whole world to see.

Comment: Can you give more details on the "NetID"? Is that based on some standard technology or is it homegrown? Searching around for details I couldn't find anything definitive. Perhaps it is based on http://www.mynetid.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

> ...we don't need or want a password. We do, however, still need a local user account so users can post, change their profile, etc.

The good news is, this is what [FIDO2 U2F](https://www.yubico.com/2018/04/yubico-and-microsoft-introduce-passwordless-login/) is meant to provide.

I've never heard of NetID before, and like the commenters I can't find much documentation about it online. I'd suggest switching to hardware security tokens with FIDO2 support. It's great.

The bad news is, there isn't Drupal support for FIDO2 U2F yet. Maybe it could be proposed as a new core module for the next major version?